# Different behavior for Django DecimalField on sQlite vs MySQL

Tags: django, django-models

I've just put online a website which was developed on sqlite3, but when deploying I needed to switch to MySQL.

Everything went well except for the products price because on sqlite and MySQL DecimalField apparently doesn't behave the same.

Consider the following model:

```
class ProductBase(models.Model):
    title   = models.CharField('Title', max_length=250)
    price   = models.DecimalField('Price', max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

In development, sqlite will allow the price to be "0" or "100" for example.

However when transferred to MySQL, the backend will also allow "0" or "100" inputs, but when the object instance is saved it's transformed automatically into "0.00" or "100.00".

I know the ORM is an abstraction level and that it has its limits due to discrepancies among database backends features.. that's why I'm asking here if it's a limitation related bug or really a bug .. before opening a new ticket..

Comment: isn't that the expected behaviour of a decimalfield? to store a decimal value?

Comment: Yeah .. but on sqlite if you enter "0" it will stay "0" and if you do the same using MySQL the "0" will become "0.00". I know what cause this different behavior, but I'm not sure it's a resolvable issue that would need a new bug report or simply a backend limitation for which the ORM can't help.

Answer (score 7):

SQLite's `DECIMAL` datatype, which is actually a `NUMERIC` in the database, does not allow specifying a size or precision; it is stored as either an `INTEGER`, a `REAL`, or a `TEXT` depending on criteria as given [in the documentation](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity). Precision information is not available to the backend, and so is not preserved.

MySQL's `NUMERIC` datatype is a true arbitrary-length fixed point type, and comes back from the database with full precision information.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.. that's pretty much what I suspected. That said, couldn't the ORM deal with this transparently by type casting the input according to the model's specifications ?

Comment: It probably could, but I don't feel it's really that important; if you require precision information then you really should be specifying it on output.